# How can I define input mask for price with jquery input mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-inputmask

I want to allow the user to enter the amount between 0 and 1000. Optionally he can enter the amount with cents.
Examples of amounts I want to allow:
199.99,
29.90,
999.99,
0.01,
10,
999

I tried this, but it doesn't really work:

```
$('.input-price').mask('000.00', {reverse: true});
```

Is there any other, working way you can propose me?

Comment: default HTML5 supports `step`, `min` and `max` attributes on the html tag. But I would try to find out what's wrong with your `.mask()` call here. Have you tried using `,` instead of `.` as the floating point seperator? Have you tried providing a custom translation object as described in the docs? Stuff like this is why I threw out jquery after default HTML5 got enough support from browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `9` placeholder, which makes the digit optional:

```js
$('.input-price').mask('099.99');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="input-price" placeholder="Enter price..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (JS)

```js
    function isNumberDot(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)&& charCode != 46 && charCode != 127) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" value="0.00"
    onKeyPress="return isNumberDot(event);"
    autocomplete="off"  onFocus="this.select();" onChange="if(this.value=='NaN' || this.value==''){this.value='0.00'};this.value=parseFloat(this.value).toFixed(2);"
    >
```

Comment: It's much better, but still allows user to enter numbers like 99.99999